# How to pass parameters to feature file in a loop?

Tags: api, for-loop, parameters, karate

I'm calling a feature file, which will run an API internally and returns a response.

`* def response_array = call read('API1.feature')`

The response here is a list of Strings. Now, I want to pass this response array (List) elements one by one to another feature file, which is expecting a String value.

```
   * def final_response = call read('API2.feature', {'id': response_array[0]}))
   * def final_response = call read('API2.feature', {'id': response_array[1]}))
   * def final_response = call read('API2.feature', {'id': response_array[2]}))
   .
   .
   .
```

Is there a way in Karate to perform the above code in a single step?